# ES6 modules in browser

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to import component in existing HTML page, below is the example. I tried with require but no luck.
`

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
     <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
    <script>
    import mycomponent from './components/mycomponent.vue'
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        'my-component': mycomponent
        }
      })
    </script>
   </body>
</head>
</html>
```

`
The import line says unexpected identifier! what went wrong here, please help.

Comment: There's a typo at "import mycomponentfrom './components/mycomponent.vue'". You are missing a space, is that causing the issue?

Comment: You are also missing a closing curly brace

Comment: `./components/mycomponent.vue` would that even resolve correctly from a public directory? Or did you place the component in public/components?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo error, still not working ! :(

Comment: @BalramSharma  Was my answer useful for you?

Comment: Thank you @YevheniiHerasymchuk, new error now "Failed to resolve module specifier './components/mycomponent.vue'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `type=module` on the script element, and the browser will treat the inline or external script as an ECMAScript module.
Here is how your code can be transformed

```
<html>
<head> 
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
     <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
    import mycomponent from './components/mycomponent.vue'
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        'my-component': mycomponent
        }
      })
    </script>
   </body>
</head>
</html>
```

You can read more about ECMAScript modules in browsers [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, the earlier error went away but still didn't work. It started giving new error. "Failed to resolve module specifier './components/mycomponent.vue'

Comment: Yes, check is it possible to open your file in browser, Ctrl+U, find this string `./components...`  and click on it. You won't be able to see the code, so check your server.
But my suggestion is to change the title of the question to "ES6 modules in the browser" and mark it as an answer, because the topic is popular.

Comment: I'm running this page from IIS server the error I'm getting there "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map." may be .vue extension and IIS is not understanding when opening it in browser. so, don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Just make it public, run through the tutorials of IIS, make this file public, open it in the browser( you have to see just code of the component)

Comment: The problem is not in Vue or IIS, just start with simple knowledge of server, client, start with simple web pages and import scripts to the page

Comment: Thank you for point to point direction, but when I change .vue extension to other like .js or .txt It shows the code of component. I am only getting that message when it's  extension is ".vue"

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with handling static files on your server. Just work with it. 
But, again, your question can be renamed to "ES6 modules in browser" and my answer is right for this question.